# How to get the most chili flavour out of a chili pepper?

Tags: chili-peppers, spicy-hot

I always find myself enjoying someone else's chili dish whether its curry, Mexicana pizza etc, more than my own. It's not the burning sensation that's lacking but more the chili flavour.

What are the guidelines to getting the most flavour out of a chili pepper in any spicy dish?

Comment: Edited, the question is very different than the original (which wasn't so bad as to deserve a hold) but has the advantage of being unquestionably fair game for this place.

Comment: Thank you. I did feel a bit hard done by. But edited it any why instead of complaining.

Comment: This shouldn't be on hold. It's not opinion based, there are techniques used to waken up a chili pepper depending on how it's being used, but that is technique based, not opinion based. In my wok cooking that includes a chili or two, I always drop the pepper pods into the hot oil before all other ingredients. It wakes up the chili and infuses the cooking oil with the pepper oils. When making chili sauces, you generally use vinegar and oil to extract the heat from the pepper.

Comment: Found a duplicate anywhy. http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/66014/how-do-you-get-the-flavor-out-of-dried-peppers .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One technique, especially in Mexican foods, for recipes that use dried chilies, is to toast the pods before using them. 
Toast them over medium heat until the pod blisters, but don't blacken too much. They are very thin, so going from done to ruined takes only a few seconds of in attention. Be careful!